# How do I add spaces to the output of my code?

Tags: c#, namespaces, output, space

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello, What is your first name?");
String firstName = Console.ReadLine();

Console.WriteLine("What is your middle Initial?");
String midInitial = Console.ReadLine();

Console.WriteLine("What is your last name");
String lastName = Console.ReadLine();

Console.WriteLine("Welcome "+ firstName + midInitial + lastName);
Console.ReadLine();
```

I want the output to be in the format `"Welcome, Mark R Golding"`, however, I end up with `"Welcome, MarkRGolding"`. How do I fix this?

I tried adding double quotes like so:
`Console.WriteLine("Welcome, " + " " firstName + " " midInitial + " " lastName);` but that just gives me errors...

Comment: you missed + before some variable names.

Comment: You should always include the error message in your question if you have code that's producing errors.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do it, the most common are:

1. Concatenate them as you're doing the rest of the strings:

   `Console.WriteLine("Welcome " + firstName + " " + midInitial + " " + lastName)`
2. You can use [composite formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/composite-formatting) by putting placeholders in the string for the variable values and follow the string with the variable names:

   `Console.WriteLine($"Welcome {0} {1} {2}", firstName, midInitial, lastName);`
3. You can use an [interpolated string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated) by prefixing the string with a `$` and putting the variable names inside the string, surrounded by curly braces:

   `Console.WriteLine($"Welcome {firstName} {midInitial} {lastName}");`

For more information on all the ways to concatenate strings, see: [How To Concatenate Multiple Strings (C# Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/how-to/concatenate-multiple-strings)